# Change value of all rows in a column of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a data frame `df` like:

```
        measure  model threshold
285   0.241715  a        0.0001
275   0.241480  a        0.0001
546   0.289773  b        0.0005
556   0.241715  b        0.0005
817   0.357532  a         0.001
827   0.269750  b         0.001
1088  0.489164  a        0.0025
```

I want to change all values in the column `model` to `'no_model'`. How do I do this?

I am currently doing `df['model'] = 'no_model'`, but I'm getting:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['model'] = 'no_model'
```

Comment: Did you try `df.loc[:, 'model'] = 'no model'`?

Comment: you mean, change the name of 'model'?

Comment: Yep @JonClements get the same warning.

Comment: You've done something prior to this call to raise this warning, probably you took a slice or filtered your original df, is your intention to work on a view of the original df or a copy?

Comment: @user2241910 no, the column name is the same, every value in column becomes 'no_model'.

Comment: @EdChum correct I have - I want to create a copy of the DF and do this thing to it.

Comment: then you need to call `copy()` on the original df: `df_copy = df.copy()` then you can do what you want to `df_copy`

Comment: @DhruvGhulati did you create a new dataframe such as `new_df = df.copy()` ?

Comment: @EdChum ok that solved it. Add as an answer so you get points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the warning because you probably either made a reference to the original df:

`df1 = df`

and then tried your code but your intention was to take a copy so you should use `copy()` to explicitly take a copy:

`df_copy = df.copy()`

this will get rid of the warning